# How to fix : NameError: name 'password' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Version : Python 3.7.4

Hi, this is my very first code. It works well if I just enter everything correctly. However, if I enter the wrong values at certain points then I get the error "NameError: name 'password' is not defined". Along, with a possible solution if you could review my code and provide me some feedback on how I could make it better than that would be awesome. Please guide me Master Yoda! :)

Solutions I have tried:
1. adding brackets, removing brackets, removing colon, adding colon.
2. Assigning variable names.
3. Read the book from which I am learning but according to the book my code is fine.
4. Read similar posts but their code is much more advanced so I cannot understand the code nor the solution.
5. Various indentations.`

This error occurs in :
 - Line 18 if I enter the wrong value for the username.
 - Line 30 if I enter the password wrong (NameError: name 'age' is not defined)
 - Line 43 NameError: name 'ans' is not

My Code :

```
#Displays what I have learnt so far : Variable assignment, comparision operators, arithmetic operators, value operators, logical operators,

print('Welcome')
print('Enter Username')
username = input()
if username == 'Evan' :
    print('Enter Password')
else:
    print('Wrong Username. Program terminated.')

if username == 'Evan' :
    password = input()
    if password == 'Great' :
        print('Additional identification confirmation required.')
    else:
        print('Wrong password. Program terminated.')

if password == 'Great':
    print('What is your age?')
    years = (27)
    age = int(input())
    if age < years :
        print('Seriously?')
    elif age > years :
        print('-_-"')
    else:
        age == years
        print('Welcome Evan!')

if age == years:
    print('Name one of the RGB colours.')
    rgb = 'Red' or 'Green' or 'Blue'
    colours = input()
    if colours == rgb :
        print('Good')
    else:
        print('Wrong Answer')

if age == years :
    print('Type Rock & Roll.')
    answer = 'Rock & Roll'
    ans = input()
if ans != answer :
    print('Learn to type.')
else:
    print('Good job!')

if age == years:
    print('Let me show you some math for entertainment :D')
result = '= '
print('2+2')
print(result + str(int(2+2)))
print('')
print('3 - 2')
print(result + str(int(3-2)))
print('')
print('2 x 2')
print(result + str(int(2*2)))
print('')
print('7 / 3')
print(7/3)
print('')
print('3 modulus 7')
print(result + str(int(3%7)))
print('')
print('2 exponent 10')
print(result + str(int(2**10)))
print('')
print('23 floor division 9')
print(result + str(int(23//9)))
```

Comment: When containing variables inside of if's or for's it is a good idea to always predefine them with an empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've *scoped* `password` into the enclosing `if` statement.

```py
if username == 'Evan' :
    password = input()
```

Move it outside that block to use it.

```py
password = None
if username == 'Evan' :
    password = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you write "program terminated", in reality it is not terminated. The program checks all the ifs and, as 'password' is not defined if you wrote the wrong username, it crashes.

The best solution is to write your code in a function. In this way, when you write "program terminated", you can return an error value and stop the program.

```
def function_name():
    #Some code
    if username == "Evan":
        #Some code
    else:
        #You want to terminate the function in this case
        return 1
    #Some code
#Function call
function_name()
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

I started 2 days ago so I haven't learnt the functions you have mentioned. I'll try it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to terminate the program, you can use the quit() function which ends the program whenever you call it.

I can see that you have repeated `if` statements i.e. they're checking the same things, so try **nested if else statements**. I would also suggest a little bit of structured code, like declaring all the variables you're going to use at the beginning of the program and initializing them to **None**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just started learning about 2 days ago so I have not reached the quit() function but I will try it.

I am very new to programing so I cannot understand what you mean by 'nest if else statements'. Also what do you mean by "initializing them to". If you could elaborate on these then I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Apologies @LightSpeed. You can google nested if-else statements. Initialising variables means that when you declare a variable, let's say **username**, you took input to fill it with a value, i.e. you "initialised" it to the user-given value. So when I said initialise it to None, if you know what None is, you could instead do: username =None **next line** username = input() . It's a standard, not always done because it makes code long, and when you have a million variables, it'll be tedious. But aside from competitive coding, in projects, it's considered a good practice. Hope this helps.